# How to bind value for Material-Multi-Select

Tags: typescript, angular6

How to bind default selected data in multi-select?

HTML Code:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="userCreation.aspId" name="aspId"   #aspId="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && aspId.invalid }" required multiple="true">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let userCreation of aspdata"  [value]="userCreation.aspId" >
     {{userCreation.officeName}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

in TS file:

```
this.userCreation.aspId = element.asplist[0].aspId
```

Comment: This: `this.userCreation.aspId` needs to be an array. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for multiselect Mat-Select must be an array,

So expected JSON should be:

```
                           Here must be an array
                                 \/\/\/
userCreation : any  = { aspId : ['name'] };
```

So if you want to add a new option then you can use:

```
this.userCreation.aspId.push('new-option')
```

[`Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3v1gcb) is a working demo:

> EDIT:

If your data is then you can use `[compareWith]` attribute:

Assuming your data is like:

```
aspId : [{"id":1,"itemName":"India"}, {"id":3, "itemName":"Australia"}]
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="userCreation.aspId" [compareWith]="compareFn" name="aspId"   #aspId="ngModel" required multiple="true">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let userCreation of dropdownList" [value]="userCreation" >
              {{userCreation.itemName}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS Code:

```
compareFn(val1: any, val2: any) {
    return val1 && val2 ? val1.id === val2.id : val1 === val2;
}
```

Comment: @GaneshGoud Does it helped?